# ember-cli and Rails 5 api date handling

Tags: ember-cli, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying out rails 5 api and ember-cli (2.11) for the first time.  I am having trouble with date handling.

I have a date attribute in rails outputting json like 
"2017-03-15"

The date (in ember inspector) becomes
Tue Mar 14 2017 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

I use a seed file to create records like:

```
Planting.create(planting_type: 'seed', planting_date_begin: Date.new(2017,8,1))
```

I only care about date (not time).  How do I get date to display correctly in Ember as well as determine if other dates are within date range (date math)?

Do I need to change my rails attribute to DateTime? If I do change to DateTime will Ember still need adjustment for timezone?  What about my seed file...will I need save like a timestamp with no timezone but with time info?

Answer (score 0):

Ember was converting my date into a time with wrong time zone.  using the add-on [https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-utc-transform](http://ember-utc-transform) changes zone to utc resolved my issue